# PHP variable to URL in address bar

Tags: php

I have the code:

```
echo('
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" > 
    <form method="POST" action="plan.php">
<p>Selectati data raportului:<br>
 <select name="SelectDR" onchange="form.submit()">
 <option value="">Select...</option>
');
```

It is a form from which I select a value.

```
$option = isset($_POST['SelectDR']) ? $_POST['SelectDR'] : false;
if ($option){
    $queryTXT = "SELECT * FROM ".$tabel." WHERE DataRaport='".$option."'";
...
```

The records of a SQLtable are filtered by the value selected from the form.

Now, what I want is to display in the url *plan.php?DataRaport& variable php*

I've tried to put in the form url (`<form method="POST" action="plan.php?DataRaport'.$option.'">`), but that doesn't show the variable.

Comment: If you want to get the DataReport from the URL, you would need to use GET

Answer (score 5):

You need GET not POST

```
<form method="GET">
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. If you want to echo this HTML every time, just use it as HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2" > 
<form method="POST" action="plan.php">
     <p>Selectati data raportului:<br>
     <select name="SelectDR" onchange="form.submit()">
     <option value="">Select...</option>
     </select>
</form>

<?php //your php stuff
```

To get the value from the URL, you need to change one thing:

```
<form method="POST" action="plan.php?DataReport=<?php echo $option?>">
```

Then you would get this variable as:

```
$dataReport = $_GET['DataReport'];
```

This would return the option value as `POST` and the `DataReport` as `GET`.

You can change the form method to `GET` if you wish, but you would then need to use `$_GET` to pick the selected option.